# aws_s3 module version id error with Ansible 2.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have simple task to download file from s3 bucket which works fine with Ansible 2.3, when I have upgraded the ansible from 2.3 to 2.4, it complain that I need to use the aws_s3 module instead of s3 which I did and getting the following error:

```
─➤ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook.yml                                                                    4 ↵


PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************************


TASK [Download the latest version of from S3 bucket] *************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Key /node/qa/1.0.483/node.tar.gz with version id None does not exist."}


PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Here is my task:

```
- name: Download the latest version of from S3 bucket
  aws_s3:
    aws_access_key: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    aws_secret_key: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    bucket: "artifacts-bucket"
    object: "/node/qa/1.0.483/node.tar.gz"
    mode: get
    dest: "node.tar.gz"
```

Few notes:
- versioning is not enabled on my s3 bucket
- installed the boto3 that is the requirement for aws_s3 module
- the exact same tasks work fine with ansible 2.3 and did give this error

```
"Key /node/qa/1.0.483/node.tar.gz with version id None does not exist."
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug due to `boto3`. Prior to porting this module to boto3 `object: /path/to/object` refered to `bucketname/path/to/object`. In 2.4 this became `bucketname//path/to/object`.

Omitting the leading / in object is a workaround. This code work for me:

```
- name: Download the latest version of from S3 bucket
  aws_s3:
    aws_access_key: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    aws_secret_key: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    bucket: "artifacts-bucket"
    object: "node/qa/1.0.483/node.tar.gz"
    mode: get
    dest: "node.tar.gz"
```

Hope it will help other. Open a bug over ansible github repo, hopefully it will fix in Ansible 2.4.1